# Showing that a wavefunction in column form is normalised

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

I am given the following wavefunction in column form:

$\psi = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4} \\ \sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}i \end{bmatrix} $

And asked to show that it is normalised.

As I understand it, the column form represents the weights of the component waveforms that make up $\psi$. I thought that these weights had to add up to $1$ for it to be normalised, so I'm a bit confused as to why there is an imaginary number as one of the weights or what that even means physically if these are supposed to be weights.

Comment: Their absolute squares are the weights.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Oh okay ty, and are these supposed to sum to 1 for it to be normalised?

Comment: The condition for $\psi$ to be normalized is $\psi^{\dagger} \psi =1$.

Answer (score 2):

**The wavefunction is complex** and doesn't have physical meaning itself. What have physical meaning is the **probability density (is real) $|\psi|^{2}$**. Your probability density is:

\begin{equation}
|\psi|^{2}=Re[\psi]^2+Im[\psi]^2=\dfrac{1}{16}\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
15
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

As always the total probability must be $1$, that is checking:

\begin{equation}
\sum |\psi|^{2}= 1
\end{equation}

That is satisfied.

In **vector formalism**, this is:

\begin{equation}
\langle \psi|\psi\rangle = 1
\end{equation}

Where $\langle \psi|$ is a row vector (and complex conjugate) and $ |\psi\rangle$ is a column vector. [Check this](https://serc.carleton.edu/matlab_computation2016/essays/160271.html).

Comment: That notation is misleading at best!  The inner product $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$ has to be a *number*, so it can't be equal to a vector.  $|\psi(x)|^2$ is a fine notation in position-space, but not in the abstract vector formalism *or* in the column-vector representation.  You're mixing the position-space formalism with the abstract vector formalism with the column-vector representation.

Comment: I think this answer is missing the the bra should be a row-vector and is trying to do element-wise multiplication of $\psi$ with its complex conjugate rather than matrix multiplication with is conjugate transpose (adjoint).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.